# Visibility transition css

Tags: css

I a currently creating a login/registration form for my website.
The default display is "Se connecter" (login) and when the user click on "S'enregistrer" (register) the form flips and reveal the other side of the card with the registration form.

Here is what it looks like : https://codepen.io/aLitschgy/pen/KKxqQbq

```
.form .login-form,
.form .register-form{
    max-height: 500px;
}


.form .login-form.hidden,
.form .register-form.hidden{
    max-height: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

(when I click on register or login the 'hidden' class is toggled on both login and register forms)

The problem is that the rotation of the form takes .8s while the change from a form to the other is instantaneous so for the first .4s you see the opposite form in the wrong way around.

What I'm trying to do is to switch the form at exactly .4s so the user doesn't see it.

I tried to make transition on max-height, on visibility with step(1) transition but it doesn't seems to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this way, adjust timeout as per your requirement.

Html and css will remains same!

**JS:**

```
 const logLink = document.querySelector(".form .login-form .register a");
  const regLink = document.querySelector(".form .register-form .register a");
  const form = document.querySelector(".form .form-box");
  const logForm = document.querySelector(".form .login-form");
  const regForm = document.querySelector(".form .register-form");
  logLink.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
    form.classList.toggle('turned')
setTimeout(()=>{
   logForm.classList.toggle('hidden');
    regForm.classList.toggle('hidden');
}, 400)
   
    event.preventDefault();
  });

  regLink.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
  
form.classList.toggle('turned')
   setTimeout(()=>{
      regForm.classList.toggle('hidden');
logForm.classList.toggle('hidden');  
   },400)
    
    event.preventDefault();
  });
```